# eventDrop not working on demo - closed

Tags: fullcalendar

I have using json events geting for mysql db but everything is working ok. I put consol.log for events eventDragStart,eventDragStop  and eventDrop. On start and stop i see that erything is working but eventDrop is not working. I have jquery 1.7 lib na ui 1.8.16 whole lib with all thing. here is link for demo www.workconcept.eu/worco/agenda-views.php 
can anybody say what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't add "closed" to the title. Since someone has posted an answer, you can choose to accept it which would indicate your issue is resolved, or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I imported your calendar initialisation code into the project I'm working on and it works fine.  The difference is as I suspected in the version of jquery.  They made a lot of event handling changes when they went to 1.7 and 1.7 breaks many things.  The current 1.7.1 fixes that incompatibility in most cases, so you may want to try that, or to be sure, go back to 1.6.2 which is what I'm using.

Comment: Thank you. your right! That is problematic situation. Should be fixed